# Highcharts 100% height of parent that have 50% height

Tags: css, highcharts

The chart set automatically full height of parents parent height. Totaly ignores his parent height.

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="huj2">
    <div class="huj">
      bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="huj">
      <div id="ChartContainer2">
        //Chart is here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ChartContainer2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.huj {
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.huj2 {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a40a0bjy/17/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your high chart container height of 100% and it will work. Below is the code solution of your fiddle.

```
#ChartContainer2 {

  width: 100%;
  height:100% ;

}
```